# How to send django url with parameters to ajax request?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Currently, I am sending url to the ajax as :

```
    $('.togglebtn').on("click",function(){
         console.log("Hello")
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:8000/toggle/2945016571198",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                  appendData(data);
                   function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("switch_{{forloop.counter}}");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = '<tr>' + data[i].line_items + ' ' + data[i].nomenclature+'</tr>' ;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
            }
  });
```

Currently, I am sending request into a static url. Can we use {% url `toggle` i.id %} to set the url dynamically in the ajax request? Does this ajax function repeats at all or not?

Answer (score 1):

Not in that way or fashion, the `{% url toggle i.id %}` is for the Django template, so that is executed when rendering the page **server** side. What you want to do is client side.

Your are also trying to use `"switch_{{forloop.counter}}"`, which won't work unless you have multiple snippets of the 'click' function. Which I would advise against since it simply doesn't make sense. You define a function once and then use it. See first example.

Best thing I can think of is exposing a 'base url' in your template and use that in javascript.
For example in your Django template:

```js
<script>
// Put the Django variable into javascript context.
toggle_base_url = {{ toggle_base_url_from_django_view_context }};
// Use it in your ajax url by combining strings.
 $('.togglebtn').on("click",function(){
         console.log("Hello")
         var obj = $(this); // Save the clicked button for reference.
         var objectId = obj.attr('id');
         var buttonId = obj.attr('data-button-id');
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: toggle_base_url + "/" + buttonId
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Cannot use 'this' in this context (IIRC), use the obj var we assigned.
                // Replace with something to find your parent container
                // Could use have a attribute on your button that points to the container.
                // Probably the number you use in the url?
                var mainContainer = obj.parent('containerclass');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = '<tr>' + data[i].line_items + ' ' + data[i].nomenclature+'</tr>' ;
                    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
                }
            }
        }
  });

</script>
```

In your Django view you do something like this:

```py
# Make a base url to reuse, remove the last part.
# So turn `/toggle/1` into `/toggle`
base_url = reverse('toggle', args=[1]).rsplit('/', 1)
context = {
    'toggle_base_url_from_django_view_context': base_url,
}
return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', context=context)
```

Comment: `{{ toggle_base_url_from_django_view_context }};` refers to?

Comment: you are simply adding the `params` part as string, so the params part is also dynamic.

Comment: Added a Django view snippit to explain the `toggle_base_url_from_django_view_context`. I understand the params is dynamic, but not where you expect to retrieve it from :) Hence the `obj.attr('id')` example, could use that for the dynamic part.

Comment: Added the `buttonId` and used that in the URL, hope that clarifies it.

Comment: args = 1 shows `_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be an iterable, not int` So, args = [1]

Comment: Right, my bad! Fixed it. Downside of writing pseudo code outside of a runserver. Hope this help you in the right direction!